# Classifier 'IOException' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: android, ioexception, android-jetpack-datastore

I am trying to read data from `preference datastore` and getting this unexpected error.

Here's a codelab from google [link1](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#6)

Here's the official doc [link2](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-read)

```
private const val DATA_STORE_NAME = "SETTINGS_STATE_OF_APP"
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = DATA_STORE_NAME)
class PreferencesDatastore(private val context: Context) {

val readData: Flow<Model> = context.dataStore.data
    .catch { exception ->
        if (exception in IOException){    // here the IOException is throwing error 
            emit(emptyPreferences())
        }else {
            throw exception
        }
    }
    .map {
       
    }
}
```

This same code is working fine in an older project.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Try to replace `in` keyword to `is` in if condition, where exception occurs. Does it solves your problem?

Comment: @roman-popov is right. Also, for datastore variables, try and avoid typing the mapping code for each element. just use a function to call all stored variable of a specific type and same to change values. look here for an example - https://github.com/Vaishnav-Kanhirathingal/CRYPTILE/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/cryptile/app_data/data_store_files/AppDataStore.kt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in using `in` keyword for testing if an object is of a given type instead of `is`. To prevent these kind of problems in future I recommed you to check [Type checks and casts in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html) and [Java instanceOf Operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof)

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you check a new question that I just posted?